# IntelliJ: Can I read/write/run a project over a network drive?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So at my office, we do Java development and have to test things in multiple environments. This is done through VMs, and the program we use is VMware.

All these VMs take up a lot of disk space, so I'm searching for ways to lower my footprint. I want to work with much, much smaller VMs, so I want to reduce the number of things I need to load into them. My big idea for this is to have a shared directory with my dev environment, and share it with my VMs. That way I can work on my dev environment on multiple OS's without having to waste the extra disk space of having duplicate copies of it.

The problem is that IntelliJ doesn't seem to like accessing a project over a network drive. It's not truly networked, since everything is local on my machine, but that's how it perceives it.

Is there any good way to set it up so that it can work with the shared directory? I feel like I might be doomed here, but if anyone would know it would be someone on this site.

Comment: If your code needs to be tested in multiple environments, then it means that you're going to *deploy* the code on multiple environments eventually, and that you're testing that to make sure it works. Which means that the shared code is not the source, or whatever binary output IntelliJ generates, but the artifacts created by your build script, and *that* is what you copy to a shared location for testing. IntelliJ should not even be aware of any sharing or network resources. You might want to read about [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Comment: the answer above by Andreas is the "correct" answer to your question. all development should be local, with code checked out from git. that aside, if you are dealing with too many heavy VMs for deployment, i would recommend looking into Docker. It uses containers within VMs to create isolated "components" (java applications or whatever) which have a much smaller footprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Windows in VMs (in *nix VMs you will not suffer from such problems).

You need to map network path to the local drive in the VM:

```
My Computer > Alt + T > Map network drive... > define you path + local drive > Finish
```

And use this local drive in IntelliJ.

To automate this procedure across VMs you can use [net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) console command.